# Filename conventions for Python

Tags: python

Why must I add an extra backslash before the file name of "black.txt" but not before "planet.txt"?

What's the difference between "b" and "p"? It would not work for file names starting with other characters either such as "a".

```
 open('C:\Python27\MyScripts\\black.txt')
```

Here's the error I get when I don't use the two backslashes before "black.txt":

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\MyScripts\script5.py", line 2, in <module>
    f = open('C:\Python27\MyScripts\black.txt')
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('r') or filename:
'C:\\Python27\\MyScripts>\x08lack.txt'
```

Comment: When specifying paths in Windows, remember that Windows is happy to use forward slashes.

Comment: @angelica did you get your question answered?

Comment: @dantiston yes, I got several good answers, thanks!

Comment: @angelica, if you feel so moved, you can [accept an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because ["\b" is a Python escape character](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals). That is, it is transformed into another character once it is processed into the string.

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals):

> The backslash (\) character is used to escape characters that otherwise have a special meaning, such as newline, backslash itself, or the quote character. String literals may optionally be prefixed with a letter 'r' or 'R'; such strings are called raw strings and use different rules for interpreting backslash escape sequences.
>
> ...
>
> Unless an 'r' or 'R' prefix is present, escape sequences in strings are interpreted according to rules similar to those used by Standard C

"\p" is not an escape character, so the backslash is converted automatically by Python on Windows for you (evidently, though I can't find documentation for this).

At the [Python interpreter prompt](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/interpreter.html) on Windows:

```
>>> a = "\b"
>>> a
'\x08'
>>> b = "\p"
>>> b
'\\p'
```

If you're writing code that might ever be used by someone else, you should think about [portability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_portability). Therefore, when writing paths, you should use [os.path.join](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join):

On Windows:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.path.join('path', 'to', 'file')
'path\\to\\file'
```

On *nix

```
>>> import os
>>> os.path.join('path', 'to', 'file')
'path/to/file'
```

If you have some other **normal** string literal, to be safe, always do a double backslash. Unless you're using [raw strings, which don't do the escape character replacement](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) (see the first paragraph).

Comment: What about [raw strings](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals)? I'm not sure about the advice 'always do a double backslash'. It's better to use raw strings.

Comment: PS thanks for the string literal documentation. I was wondering why Google linked me to that page...

Comment: What's a normal string literal? I'm not sure about this superstitious 'just to be safe'.

Comment: @PeterWood it's a string literal that's not a raw string. I can't find an official designation for such a thing, so feel free to propose a different one.

Comment: @PeterWood it's not superstitious, it's not relying on perceived inconsistent functions, which is exactly what the OP is experiencing.

Comment: The advice to always do something, whether you need it or not, doesn't seem good. If you need back-slashes and don't need escape characters, use a raw string.

Answer (score 1):

Please see this : https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html

"\b" is an escape sequence that removes the last character from a string. However, "\p" is not an escape sequence.

Comment: thank you-that explains why I couldn't use a filename that started with an "a" as well.

Answer (score 1):

The reasons cited above are all correct.  A quick solution when using hardcoded paths on Windows is to use raw strings.

```
 f = open(r'C:\Python27\MyScripts\black.txt')
```

Notice the extra **r** right before C:?  That tells Python that it should not consider anything as an escape char.  The term is also **raw string**.

The advantages?

None of the funky / vs \ stuff.  Windows likes backslashes, let it do so.

You can cut & paste paths directly from somewhere else, without fussing with \\.

Just need to remember to add that r right before the quotes r'foo\bar' or r"foo\bar"

On the other hand, if you are building path strings yourself, I highly suggest you get acquainted with **os.path.join** (and **os.path.sep** which is the os path separator as a constant and which you should require less often).  With a bit of thought, you should be able to run programs on Windows and Linux/OSX without any path-related special cases.  Though the "C:/D:..." Windows drives vs Unix mount points can still get in the way sometimes.

Last thing.  I can't confirm now, not being on Windows, but I kinda remember that raw strings don't handle trailing slashes very well.  r"C:\temp\" will mess things up, r"C:\temp" works just fine.